# Splitting a String from byte array

Tags: python-3.x, logging, plc, snap7

I am completely new to python and PLC. I received a String from a particular tag of Siemens PLC in the byte array format like this `(b'\xfe\x07Testing\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')`I need to take only the String "Testing" and display it in the GUI. I don't know how to Split "Testing" from this byte array. Can anyone please help me in achieving it. I am using python 3.

The value is set to String format in PLC software before sending. I have done the following code for reading the tag value

```
import snap7
from snap7.util import *
import struct
import snap7.client
import logging

DB_NUMBER = ***
START_ADDRESS = 0
SIZE = 255                           

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
plc = snap7.client.Client()
plc.connect('My IP address',0,0)

plc_info = plc.get_cpu_info()
print(plc_info)

state = plc.get_cpu_state()
print(state)
db = plc.db_read(DB_NUMBER, START_ADDRESS, SIZE)
print(db)
```

I am getting the output as a byte array.

`(b'\xfe\x07Testing\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')`

Comment: PLCs often send the length of the string prior to the text. In this case \x07 since 'Testing' has seven characters.

Comment: @ lcecl  Yah That's right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any further information on whether the string is always at the same position or stuff like that, I can only provide this very static answer:

```
# The bytearray you gave us
barray = bytearray(b'\xfe\x07Testing\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')
# Start at index 2, split at first occurrence of 0byte and decode it to a string
print(barray[2:].split(b"\x00")[0].decode("utf-8"))
>>> Testing
```

Comment: Or count the bytes, `barray[2:9].decode("utf-8")` to slice to get the string directly.

Comment: Sure, if the string always has the same length.

Comment: @ js-on . Length of the string will vary but the position in which it gets displayed remains the same.

Comment: @js-on . Thank you very much I got the output by using this code `print(barray[2:].split(b"\x00")[0].decode("utf-8"))
>>> Testing`

Answer (score -1):

```
a = '\xfe\x07Testing\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
b = a.split("\x00")[0][2:]
```

Will give b as:

```
'Testing'
```